# SQLException while creating a table in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

In my project application, I'm creating a table dynamically. I'm using a JSP page to receive the table values from the user and then creating the table from a servlet (by invoking a createTable function written in a java file) in MySql database.

function for creating table in "CreateTable.java":

```
public void table(String name, String col1, String type1, String null1, String key) throws SQLException {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ? ? ? , PRIMARY KEY (?))";

    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, "`myDb`."+name);
    stmt.setString(2, col1);
    stmt.setString(3, type1);
    stmt.setString(4, null1);
    stmt.setString(5, key);

    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Servlet Controller.java  :

```
if (action.equals("createTable")) {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String null3 = request.getParameter("null1");
    String type3 = request.getParameter("type1");
    String key = request.getParameter("key");
    CreateTable createTable = new CreateTable(conn1);
    try {
        if (col2 == "" && col3 == "" && col4 == "" && col5 == "" && col6 == "" && col7 == ""    && col8 == "" && col9 == "" && col10 == "" && col11 == "" && col12 == "") {
            createTable.table(name, col1, type1, null1, key);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/memberpanel.jsp").forward(request, response);
            // request.setAttribute("message", "");
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            out.println("window.alert('Your table created successfully')");
            out.write("setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='memberpanel.jsp'},1000);");
            out.write("setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='Index.jsp'},1000);");
            out.println("</script>");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

When executing, I'm receiving this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''`myDb`.admin' (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'rescue' 'VARCHAR(750)' 'NOT NUL' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2444)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
    at queries.CreateTable.table(CreateTable.java:478)
    at controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:504)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

myDb is my database.
admin, rescue, not null, varchar(750), rescue are my test values for table name,col. name, null or  not null value, data type and primary key.

Also I've tried to change the syntax accordingly such as without database name and many things, but still receiving same error. 
Connection to database is working fine.

If someone can please help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code will never be called - you'll need to learn how to compare strings in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use query parameters like that for "non value" placeholders.

Instead, build the query as a single string in Java, then execute the string.

You can get something similar using `String.format()`:

```
String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, %s %s %s , PRIMARY KEY (%s))", "`myDb`."+name, col1, type1, null1, key);
```

Comment: Never accept outside input into a SQL statement without some sort of sanity check.

Comment: But it's still not working, it says "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key" and when I'm not entering any value for primary key- definitely it's showing "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1", because of absence of primary key(%s) value.  Please help.

Comment: @Abhishek what value is `key` when there is no key? (Ie null, blank, ?)

Comment: @std I seriously doubt a utility method that creates tables has the possibility of an external/untrusted client.

Comment: So always trust the client?  There is **never** a chance of an issue?  When there is a trivial way to make sure?

Comment: key is the string that stores primary key entered by user.

Comment: @stu Unless you provide a pathway, there won't be one ( reflection notwithstanding). If you're in doubt, there are tools (eg Fortify) that can analyse your code and report if there are untreated parameters that have an external source. Oh - OP has just posted that the parameters are from external. In that case I would recommend sanitising the input, however that is out of scope to answering the question, which technically doesn't need an alternative to andwer why he's getting the error.

Comment: @Bohemian key is the String variable that stores primary key entered by user in a text box named 'key'

Comment: @Bohemian Yes it worked. I just removed the id which was auto_incrementing and now the table has created successfully. Thanks a lot.